# Neo4J triplets loaded is 0

Tags: neo4j, rdf, neo4j-apoc, knowledge-graph, neosemantics

I am trying an example for knowledge graph. When i run this command
`:play https://guides.neo4j.com/nlp_knowledge_graphs`
some querys will be present and i am running that. But when i run the command in 5th slide, I should get triplets loaded to be some thousands. I am getting 0 and termination status is also "KO" but it should be "OK".
In extraInfo i got error like this:-> *"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"*

[image: Preview]Here is the [github link](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/nlp-knowledge-graph).

When i am executing Software systems, Programming languages, Data formats I am getting same result as "KO" and 0.[image: Neo4J Desktop when DB is running]

Please help me here. I already imported APOC, Graph Data science Library and Neosemantics(n10s).

The result should be like this for Software systems.[image: Result Preview]

Comment: cannot reproduce it, I run the first query of the play slide 5, to get the software system taxonomy and got 2046 triples

Comment: how.. i am not getting that? In files should we need to import anything.. likes articles.csv in my image

Comment: can you share your database Neo4J desktop screenshot. It might help for me.

Comment: there is nothing to import before slide 5, CSV files will be imported later on in the tutorial. I just started the Docker container, logged in, added the uniqe constraint in slide 4, the run the first query on slide 5. I mean, there is nothing to do here, just click on the query in the slide. I'm getting 2046 triples, because the tutorial itself indeed is 2 years old, so Wikidata for sure has been changed during time

Comment: you got status "KO" - I found somebody having a similar issue [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t5/integrations/termination-status-quot-ko-quot/td-p/44672) - the answer was that there was some network issue. You should check your Docker setup and or proxy or the like.

Comment: yeah thanks but it is someother issue. Mt issue is different from theirs.